# Java mergesort, should the "merge" step be done with queues or arrays?

Tags: java, algorithm

This is not homework, I don't have money for school so I am teaching myself whilst working shifts at a tollbooth on the highway (long nights with few customers)

I was trying to implement a simple "mergesort" by *thinking* first, stretching my brain a little if you like for some actual learning, and *then* looking at the solution on the manual I am using: "2008-08-21 | The Algorithm Design Manual | Springer | by Steven S. Skiena | ISBN-1848000693".

I came up with a solution which implements the "merge" step using an array as a buffer, I am pasting it below. The author uses queues so I wonder:

- Should queues be used instead?
- What are the advantages of one method Vs the other? (obviously his method will be better as he is a top algorist and I am a beginner, but I can't quite pinpoint the strengths of it, help me please)
- What are the tradeoffs/assumptions that governed his choice?

Here is my code (I am including my implementation of the splitting function as well for the sake of completeness but I think we are only reviewing the `merge` step here; I do not believe this is a Code Review post by the way as my questions are specific to just one method and about its performance in comparison to another):

```
package exercises;
public class MergeSort {
  private static void merge(int[] values, int leftStart, int midPoint,
      int rightEnd) {
    int intervalSize = rightEnd - leftStart;
    int[] mergeSpace = new int[intervalSize];
    int nowMerging = 0;
    int pointLeft = leftStart;
    int pointRight = midPoint;
    do {
      if (values[pointLeft] <= values[pointRight]) {
        mergeSpace[nowMerging] = values[pointLeft];
        pointLeft++;
      } else {
        mergeSpace[nowMerging] = values[pointRight];
        pointRight++;
      }
      nowMerging++;
    } while (pointLeft < midPoint && pointRight < rightEnd);
    int fillFromPoint = pointLeft < midPoint ? pointLeft : pointRight;
    System.arraycopy(values, fillFromPoint, mergeSpace, nowMerging,
        intervalSize - nowMerging);
    System.arraycopy(mergeSpace, 0, values, leftStart, intervalSize);
  }
  public static void mergeSort(int[] values) {
    mergeSort(values, 0, values.length);
  }
  private static void mergeSort(int[] values, int start, int end) {
    int intervalSize = end - start;
    if (intervalSize < 2) {
      return;
    }
    boolean isIntervalSizeEven = intervalSize % 2 == 0;
    int splittingAdjustment = isIntervalSizeEven ? 0 : 1;
    int halfSize = intervalSize / 2;
    int leftStart = start;
    int rightEnd = end;
    int midPoint = start + halfSize + splittingAdjustment;
    mergeSort(values, leftStart, midPoint);
    mergeSort(values, midPoint, rightEnd);
    merge(values, leftStart, midPoint, rightEnd);
  }
}
```

Here is the reference solution from the textbook: (it's in C so I am adding the tag)

```
merge(item_type s[], int low, int middle, int high)
{
  int i; /* counter */
  queue buffer1, buffer2; /* buffers to hold elements for merging */
  init_queue(&buffer1);
  init_queue(&buffer2);
  for (i=low; i<=middle; i++) enqueue(&buffer1,s[i]);
  for (i=middle+1; i<=high; i++) enqueue(&buffer2,s[i]);
  i = low;
  while (!(empty_queue(&buffer1) || empty_queue(&buffer2))) {
    if (headq(&buffer1) <= headq(&buffer2))
      s[i++] = dequeue(&buffer1);
    else
      s[i++] = dequeue(&buffer2);
  }
  while (!empty_queue(&buffer1)) s[i++] = dequeue(&buffer1);
  while (!empty_queue(&buffer2)) s[i++] = dequeue(&buffer2);
}
```

Comment: You can implement them with either one.  In order to be efficient, you need to use a collection that has constant access time to one of its ends, as well as constant insert time to the other end.  Either arrays or queues can serve this purpose.  You can also abuse stacks into working this way, or lists in general.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/23695092/3315914

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abstractly, a queue is just some object that supports the enqueue, dequeue, peek, and is-empty operations.  It can be implemented in many different ways (using a circular buffer, using linked lists, etc.)

Logically speaking, the merge algorithm is easiest to describe in terms of queues.  You begin with two queues holding the values to merge together, then repeatedly apply peek, is-empty, and dequeue operations on those queues to reconstruct a single sorted sequence.

In your implementation using arrays, you are effectively doing the same thing as if you were using queues.  You have just chosen to implement those queues using arrays.  There isn't necessarily "better" or "worse" than using queues.  Using queues makes the high-level operation of the merge algorithm clearer, but might introduce some inefficiency (though it's hard to say for certain without benchmarking).  Using arrays might be slightly more efficient (again, you should test this!), but might obscure the high-level operation of the algorithm.  From Skienna's point of view, using queues might be better because it makes the high-level details of the algorithm clear.  From your point of view, arrays might be better because of the performance concerns.

Hope this helps!

Comment: But it's a sorting algorithm! Where would you compromise on the side of performance Vs clarity if not in a sorting algorithm? Admittedly, and this might be the whole point of it, probably not in a book meant for teaching. Aren't the queue checks in the end, at least one of them, useless anyway? (one should know from which queue to pick the remaining items once the first has been depleted, shouldn't one?)

Comment: @Robottinosino- In a textbook, I think it's perfectly okay to write code that is suboptimal in order to get the high-level idea across.  As an example, a very easy way to get a huge performance increase in mergesort is to terminate the recursion when the array size gets below some threshold (say, 24), then to switch to mergesort for those smaller arrays.  You could also optimize the code by preallocating just one temporary array, rather than many smaller arrays.  Your optimization (copy one entire array rather than one element at a time) also falls into this category (continued...)

Comment: @Robottinosino- The point of the textbook is to show off the ideas that go into mergesort, rather than to aggressively optimize the code.  You absolutely can speed the code up by using other techniques, but doing so makes it much harder to see what's going on.  Remember, this is a book about algorithm design, not performance tuning.

Comment: It's actually not only a textbook, but a great one at that IMO! Anyway, I even find the "concept" of queues used there less intuitive than simple array copying... might be a mindset type of thing.

Answer (score 0):

You're worrying about minor constant factors which are largely down to the quality of your compiler.  Given that you *seem to be* worried about that, arrays are your friend.  Below is my C# implementation for integer merge-sort which, I think, is close to as tight as you can get.  [EDIT: fixed a buglet.]

If you want to do better in practice, you need something like natural merge-sort, where, instead of merging up in powers of two, you simply merge adjacent non-decreasing sequences of the input.  This is certainly no worse than powers-of-two, but is definitely faster when the input data contains *some* sorted sequences (i.e., anything other than a purely descending input sequence).  That's left as an exercise for the student.

```
int[] MSort(int[] src) {
    var n = src.Length;
    var from = (int[]) src.Clone();
    var to = new int[n];
    for (var span = 1; span < n; span += span) {
        var i = 0;
        for (var j = 0; j < n; j += span + span) {
            var l = j;
            var lend = Math.Min(l + span, n);
            var r = lend;
            var rend = Math.Min(r + span, n);
            while (l < lend && r < rend) to[i++] = (from[l] <= from[r] ? from[l++] : from[r++]);
            while (l < lend)             to[i++] = from[l++];
            while (r < rend)             to[i++] = from[r++];
        }
        var tmp = from; from = to; to = tmp;
    }
    return from;
}
```